# How to remove a layout from an AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to remove the layout where I have a button that shows a alertdiablog, it has a button that I want to delete the layout. This layout is on a TableLayout called parent layout. Now I just can remove all layouts in the table layout but I just want one.

```
 public OnClickListener editButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
   {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // get all necessary GUI components


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuCne.this);

          builder.setPositiveButton("Remove", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                parentLayout.removeAllViews();

            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any one of the removeView()(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView(android.view.View)) methods but not `removeAllViews()`. If you have an `id` for the `View` you want to remove just inflate it using its `id` and call

```
parentLayout.removeView(aView);  // where aView is the View you inflated to remove
```

there is also `removeViewAt(Index i)` to remove a view in a `layout` at that position.